# Looping backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I have a vb.net application that I want to be made a) visible and b) topmost when the activewindow is set to my requirements - this part I have covered off fine.

What I want to be able to do is to use the backgroundworker to actively monitor this on a continuous loop - again I have covered this off fine.

The problem I am having is that when I am selecting a combobox, I cannot make a selection due to interference from the bgw - almost like when I click on the combobox to show the list, the bgw seems to almost do a click away from the combobox closing the list.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
Private Delegate Sub progressDelegate()

Private Sub frmApp_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Me.bgwActiveWindow.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub

Private Sub bgwActiveWindow_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgwActiveWindow.DoWork

    Dim CheckWindow As progressDelegate

    CheckWindow = New progressDelegate(AddressOf SetAppTopMost)
    Me.Invoke(CheckWindow)

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

End Sub

Private Sub SetAppTopMost()

    Dim bol As Boolean

    If getActiveWindowTitle.IndexOf("Microsoft Outlook") <> -1 Or _
       getActiveWindowTitle.IndexOf(My.Settings.AppName) <> -1 Then
        bol = True
    Else
        bol = False
    End If

    Me.Visible = bol
    Me.TopMost = bol

End Sub

Private Sub bgwActiveWindow_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgwActiveWindow.RunWorkerCompleted

    bgwActiveWindow.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub
```

Comment: This is easy enough to figure out on your own.  Simplify the code down.  Remove the background worker.  You will most likely find that setting the `Visible` or `TopMost` property is closing up the drop down list.

Comment: If the backgroundworker is removed, there is no process in place to actively watch the activewindow selection i.e the app should only be displayed when outlook is the active window otherwise set to hidden and not topmost.

Comment: My comment was in regards to you debugging your own code.  It was not intended as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

as Praveen mentioned, check the state before setting it, to prevent setting focus to the window again. also, don't recreate the backworker thread each time:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Private Sub bgwActiveWindow_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgwActiveWindow.DoWork
    Do
        ' backworker code
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Loop While True
End Sub
```

of course, you'll either have to implement the 'supportscancellation' junk, or simple set a flag in your main thread and poll that on each loop and exit/break if you want to cancel.

you could also use a timer, which won't lock the thread.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add an additional check in your SetAppTopMost sub.

```
if Me.Visible = True then exit sub
```

This line should be 1st line. Since you are trying to show the form every 100ms, you are loosing focus.